# Python: Remove numbers with the same floor function from a list

Tags: python, list, floor

I have this list

```
x = [1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 4.5]
```

I want to delete the numbers with same floor function and get the first number of each integers as:

```
x = [1.1, 2.1, 3.0, 4.5]
```

I tried

```
x = [1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 4.5]
def h(l): 
    y = []
    for i in l: 
        if int(i) != int(i+1):
            z = i 
            y.append(z) 
    return(y)
print(h(x))
```

But when I print it yields the same result as the list

Comment: What did you try? Can you show your latest attempt and explain what difficulties you are having?

Comment: I tried

`x = [1.1, 2.1, 3.0, 4.5]`
`def h(l):`
    `y = []`
    `for i in l:`
        `if int(i) != int(i+1):`
            `z = i `
            `y.append(z)`
    `return(y)`
But it yields the same result as the list x

Comment: When you said "get the first occurrence...", are we to assume the list is sorted?

Comment: @Danny Please put that code in your question and format it using the formatting tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` if `x` is not sorted sort it first

```
out = [next(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(x, floor)]
out
# [1.1, 2.1, 3.0, 4.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

A little key mapping on the min function and set to list conversion works:

```
import numpy as np

x = [1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 4.5]
z = list(set([min(x, key=lambda i: i - np.floor(c) if i >= np.floor(c) else max(x)) for c in x]))
print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution than using `itertools.groupby` that neither assumes your input data is sorted  nor assumes you wish your output to be sorted is the following:

```
def first_floor(numbers):
    seen = set()
    for x in numbers:
        f = floor(x)
        if f not in seen:
            seen.add(f)
            yield x
```

Then:

```
>>> x = [1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 4.5]
>>> list(first_floor(x))
[1.1, 2.1, 3.0, 4.5]
```

For sorted data this is almost as fast.  For unsorted data its much faster than sorting and using `groupby`

```
>>> x = [random.random()*10 for i in range(100)]
>>> %timeit [next(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(x), floor)]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 19 µs per loop
>>> %timeit list(first_floor2(x))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 12.6 µs per loop
```